# Argument of type 'typeof AuthGuard' is not assignable

Tags: angular2-routing

I've been trying to find the solution for this issue even here on Stackoverflow, and after more than a week, I give up. Please help.

**I got this error on auth.guard.ts****strong text**

ERROR in src/app/services/auth.guard.ts(5,2): error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof AuthGuard' is not assignableto parameter of type '({ providedIn: Type | "root"; } & ValueSansProvider) | ({ providedIn: Type | "root"; } & StaticClassSansProvider) | ({ providedIn: Type | "root"; } & ConstructorSansProvider) | ({ ...; } & ExistingSansProvider) | ({ ...; } & FactorySansProvider) | ({ ...; } & ClassSansProvider)'.
  Type 'typeof AuthGuard' is not assignable to type '{ providedIn: Type | "root"; } & ClassSansProvider'.
    Type 'typeof AuthGuard' is not assignable to type '{ providedIn: Type | "root"; }'.
      Property 'providedIn' is missing in type 'typeof AuthGuard'.
src/app/services/bike.service.ts(22,13): error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

```
**My AppRoutingModule:**

import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { ViewRegistrationComponent } from './components/view-registration/view-registration.component';
import { CallbackComponent } from './components/callback/callback.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
   {
    path: 'admin/view/:id',
    component: ViewRegistrationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'callback',
    component: CallbackComponent
  }
];
...

**My authGard.ts**

import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public authService: AuthService) {

    }
        canActivate() {
            if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.authService.login();
            }
        }

}


bikeService.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable()
export class BikeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getBikes() {
   const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
     return this.http.get('/server/api/v1/bikes',
     {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token)});
  }

  getBike(id: number) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
     return this.http.get('/server/api/v1/bikes', + id,
     {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer' + token)});
  }

  createBikeRegistration(bike) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(bike);
         return this.http.post('/server/api/v1/bikes/save', body, httpOptions);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have forgotten the parentheses after `@Injectable` in your authGuard.ts.

Try `@Injectable()`.